# How to query counts of unique row combinations in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's assume for simplicity's sake that a group of invited guests visit my website to RSVP to a party and select a meal. They can choose every item on their plate from a list of available items, so one guest may request 3 items and another may request 5 or some other quantity.

On the RSVP deadline date, the party organizer is sent a list of each combination of meal ordered and its quantity. Example:

**(5x) Steak, mashed potatoes, chocolate cake

(3x) Roasted chicken, fingerling potatoes, cobb salad, white bread roll, panna cotta**

Each item an invited guest chooses is represented in an *Items* table as its own row. Each unique InviteId represents one person's selections, so in the sample data below, one person has chosen 3 itema and the other wants 5:

[image: Sample data]

I am looking to write a query/view/stored procedure to generate the counts of all the possible combinations. I was initially heading in the direction of making a temp table with bit columns to represent each of the 36 possible selections but even then am not sure how to finish it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please share some sample data and expected result as text/DDL,DML

Comment: please check this link(https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to know more on how to ask/improve your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a pain in SQL Server (until the most recent version).  You can aggregate the items together, by doing something like:

```
select i.inviteid,
       stuff( (select ',' + cast(i2.requesteditemid)
               from items i2
               where i2.inviteid = i.inviteid
               order by i2.requreditemid
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as items
from (select distinct inviteid from items i) i;
```

You can then get the list with an additional level of aggregation:

```
with ii as (
      select i.inviteid,
             stuff( (select ',' + cast(i2.requesteditemid)
                     from items i2
                     where i2.inviteid = i.inviteid
                     order by i2.requreditemid
                     for xml path ('')
                    ), 1, 1, ''
                  ) as items
      from (select distinct inviteid from items i) i
     )
select items, count(*)
from ii
group by items;
```

This produces the item ids in a list -- which is the only data actually provided in your question.  If you want the names of items, you'll want to be careful that the item names do not have commas in them (to prevent ambiguity).  The `order by` is also very important . . . because you want `1,2,3` to match `3,2,1`.

Comment: This worked perfectly with a few extra joins for my particular data situation. Thank you!